# How many terms lies between

Tags: sequences-and-series

If a have a series from $n^2$ to $(2n)^2$, i.e. $n^2+(n+1)^{2} +...+ (2n)^2$,  how many terms lie between $n^2$ and $(2n)^2$ ?  Is it $n+1$ terms, or is it $n$ terms, and how to prove that.

Comment: The terms in this series do not make any sense. $n^2$ is a perfect square. $(n+1)^2$ is also a perfect square. $2n^2$ is **not** a perfect square. One cannot use your description in order to deduce the formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write theses terms as $n+0, n+1,\dots ,n+n$, and you will see there is nothing to prove: they're numbered by the second term of each sum, so they are $n+1$ in number.